# Does AEM auto create a S3 bucket if it can't find one

Tags: amazon-s3, aem

I am using AEM 6.2 with S3 bucket as data store. I have noticed that there is no validation for bucket names in AEM and it creates a bucket if it can't find the one defined in the configuration? Is this expected or should AEM throw an error if a bucket is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is 'yes'.

AEM tries to connect to the bucket via following options:

1. Credentials provided in your datastore config files.
2. AWS IAM access

If the configured bucket is not found from above methods and no security exception is thrown it will try to create a bucket with the given name in the configured region.

This bucket creation step is only successful if the AEM AWS connector has permissions to create a bucket otherwise you will see an exception.

Comment: Is there any configuration to stop AEM from creating buckets?

Comment: There is no configuration for this but you can control it via your AWS permission.